# Can I put store a string in jquery ajax like this?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

See the code below. I don't know if that possible or not, I have a string like $id in my search.php, I want to put it into bp_core_get_user_domain(), the reason I need to do that because bp_core_get_user_domain() is not working in my search.php.

```js
$.post("search.php", 
{
 search_text: $(".result_tag").text()
},
       
function(data)
{
   var $user_link="<?php echo bp_core_get_user_domain(can I put a string here? )?>";
   $("#result").html($user_link) 
});
```

Comment: why don't you try it and see if it works or not?

Comment: I just tried, it doesn't work

Comment: Does the string have double-quotes? What are the contents of your string?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
var $user_link = "<?php echo bp_core_get_user_domain('" + your_string_here + "') ?>";
```

Comment: Once the `<?php` starts, string concatenation with `+` is wildly incorrect. And PHP variables use the `$` prefix convention. And even if this is what OP wanted to do, you can't send Javascript variables into PHP this way. Simply put, this is just plain wrong.